# Does Resharper Code clean up support this

Tags: .net, resharper

I have a project with a bunch of classes with methods that look like this:

```
public class Person {
    private string _name;
    ...

    public void setName(string name) {
        this._name = name;
    }
    public string getName()
    {
        return this._name;
    }
    ....
}
```

Is there a way to get reSharpers Code cleanup feature (or any other tool out there) to refactor the above code to this.

```
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm guessing there isn't any tool that does this, but it never hurts to ask right?

Thanks

Comment: Since you found the answer, you might want to post it as a separate answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DevExpress Refactor! Pro](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Refactoring/) has a "Convert to Auto-implemented Property" refactoring.

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed that Resharper has this feature as well. It was under the "Refactor This" command.